# How to enable the radio transmitter on yureka

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, cellular-radio, micromax-yu-yureka

So just a couple of hours ago, I unlocked the device's boot loader and after boot up, I noticed a strange app in the app drawer which was called radio transmitter. I excitedly opened the app. But, the thing is that, right after boot up, the everything was kind of super laggy and amidst the lag I killed the radio transmitter. Now, its gone from the app drawer. How can I get it back?